# How to change the src on a video tag with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to be able to click on the link that is listed below which will load my video player with a variable that is the movie I want to play on my site. I cannot get it to play or load or even display the alert message for the tag.

New Method:

```
    function setMovie(dir,movie){
    alert('Entered function setMovie');
        var m = document.getElementById("movie");
        var s = m.getElementsByTagName('source')[0];
        var temp = dir + '\';
            temp = temp + movie;
            s.setAttribute('source',temp);
        alert(temp);
    }

    function setM(){
    alert("Test");
    }
```

Video Tag:

```
  <video id="mm" width="520" height="340" controls>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Code:

```
  <a onclick="setMovieName('M','00203.144p.mp4');">From Russia With Love (1963)</a>
```

M is the directory that the movies are in.

```
 function setMovie(dir,movie){
    alert('Entered function setMovie');
        var m = document.getElementById("movie");
        var s = m.getElementsByTagName('source')[0];
        var temp = dir + '\';
            temp = temp + movie;
            s.setAttribute('source',temp);
        alert(temp);
    }

    function setM(){
    alert("Test");
    }
```

www.jamesbond.sw is the test web site for my own use.

[image]

If you notice that the variable name is getting truncated and missing zeroes and other portions of my variable. I would like to know why this is the case.

All the source code:

This is the new source code which is still not working. The www.jamesbond.sw is the home page that I have this up on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Moviereviews</title>
    <link   rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="css/images/favicon.ico"/>
    <link   rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css" href="css/style.css"    media="all"/>
    <link   rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css" href="css/colorbox.css" media="all"/>
    <script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setMovie(dir,movie){
        alert('Entered function setMovie');
            var m = document.getElementById("movie");
            var s = m.getElementsByTagName('source')[0];
            var temp = dir + '\';
                temp = temp + movie;
                s.setAttribute('src',temp);
        }

        function setM(){
        alert("Test");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
 <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="light-bg">
            <div class="shell">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="socials">
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com" class="facebook-ico">facebook-ico</a>
                        <a href="http://www.twitter.com"  class="twitter-ico">twitter-ico</a>
                        <a href="http://www.youtube.com"  class="you-tube-ico">you-tube-ico</a>
                    </div>
                    <h1 id="logo"><a href="www.jamesbond.ws">Moviereviews</a></h1>
                    <nav id="navigation">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="www.jamesbond.ws">The James Bond Movie Site</a></li> <!--can be repeated to make new cells -->
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            <div class="main">
                    <section class="content">
                        <div class="post">
                            <div class="post-inner">
                                <div class="img-holder">
                                    <center>
                                        <video id="movie" width="520" height="340" controls>
                                               <source src="M\00203.144p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                        </video>
                                    </center>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
               <div class="post">
                    <aside class="sidebar">
                        <div class="widget">
                            <h3 class="widgettitle">James Bond Movies</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a onclick="setM();">Test</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00098.144p.mp4');">Dr. No. (1962)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00098.144p.mp4');">From Russia With Love (1963)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00202.144p.mp4');">Goldfinger (1964)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00203.144p.mp4');">Thuderball (1965)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00204.144p.mp4');">You Only Live Twice (1967)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00205.144p.mp4');">On Her Majesty's Secret Service (1969)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00206.144p.mp4');">Diamonds Are Forever (1971)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00207.144p.mp4');">Live and Let Die (1973)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00208.144p.mp4');">The Man with the Golden Gun (1974)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00209.144p.mp4');">The Spy Who Loved Me (1977)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00210.144p.mp4');">Moonraker (1979)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00211.144p.mp4');">For Your Eyes Only (1981)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00212.144p.mp4');">Octopussy (1983)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00213.144p.mp4');">A View To A Kill (1985)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00214.144p.mp4');">The Living Daylights (1987)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00215.144p.mp4');"></a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00216.144p.mp4');">Licence to Kill (1989)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00217.144p.mp4');">Goldeney (1995)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00218.144p.mp4');">Tomorrow Never Dies (1997)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00219.144p.mp4');">The World is Not Enough (1999)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00220.144p.mp4');">Die Another Day (2002)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00221.144p.mp4');">Casino Royal (2006)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00222.144p.mp4');">Quantum of Solace (2008)</a></li>
                                <li><a onclick="setMovie('M','00223.144p.mp4');">Skyfall (2012)</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </aside>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
 </div> 

<iframe width="620" height="438" src="http://www.playmycode.com/play/embed/jayenkai/space-clusters" 
       marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: none; border-size: 0; overflow: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

I am starting to wonder if the onclick is working. The test function is not showing the alert box so I am not completely certain as to why that would be the case.

```
<li><a onclick="setM();">Test</a></li>
```

Comment: First-off, you need to escape the double-quotes in your `onclick` attribute value, or convert them to single-quotes.

Comment: I changed this but still not working. The variable is getting truncated in side of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setMovieName(name){
    var vid = document.getElementById('mm');
    var src = vid.getElementsByTagName('source')[0];
    src.setAttribute('src',name);
}
```

The getElementsByTagName('source')[0] will get the first  element which is what you're looking for.

The setAttribute('src',name); will change the src="" of the first  to what you pass to the function.

Comment: I will see if this will work. What does the 'source' actually mean and the [0] mean?

Comment: I am course on the set attribute does it have to be source or src? I still cannot get it to work with the variables.

Comment: Attribute should be src.